# Set of measure zero covered by cubes

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E \subset R^2$ be measurable s.t. for every $x \in E$ there exists a sequence of cubes $\{Q_n(x)\}$ centered at $x$ with side lengths tending to $0$ with
$$|E \cap Q_n(x)| \leq \frac{1}{2} |Q_n(x)|$$
To prove $|E|=0$. Any hints? Thank you!

Comment: Apply Lebesgue's differentiation theorem to the indicator function $1_E$.